# twitter bootstrap breadcrumbs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, breadcrumbs

For breadcrumbs to work in twitter bootstrap, my understanding is that you just set the ul class to breadcrumb, here is an example:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="#">Home</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
<li><a href="#">Library</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
<li class="active">Data</li>
</ul>
```

however, here is our code to make a dropdown in the nav bar:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <% menu_item[:children].each do |submenu_item| %>
                <%= render :partial => 'cms/menus/bootstrap_menu_child', :locals => { :submenu_item => submenu_item } %>
              <% end %>
</ul>
```

do i just add  class="dropdown-menu breadcrumb"?  Tried that, didn't work.  Is there somewhere to then "turn on" bread crumbs perhaps?  Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Dropdown menus and breadcrumbs are totally separate features.

Comment: Well, if I start at Home, then go to a dropdown in the nav bar, and choose "Contact", I want to see a breadcrumbs bar that shows "Home>Contact"  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap breadcrumbs are just a set of CSS styles; the dropdown functionality is [included as a jQuery plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html).
Consequently, adding `class="breadcrumb"` will only style existing elements, not generate the breadcrumb navigation. You'll have to do that in your code.